# Insert element and add prefix using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to add or insert another element and attribute `<vat:IRmark Type="generic"/>` after the `<DefaultCurrency>`. And, there is a certain group which is the `<Group>` element that I need to add a prefix. I almost did it, but the insertion of element didn't working. Here is my sample test file:

**INPUT File:**

```
<Data>
<Record>
    <ID>123-AAA</ID>
    <Date>2017-04-23</Date>
    <Group>
        <Hdr>
            <ID>833-AAA</ID>
            <DefaultCurrency>GBP</DefaultCurrency>
            <Sender>truth</Sender>
        </Hdr>
    </Group>
</Record>
```

**GENERATED OUTPUT:**

```
<Data>
<Record xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:vat="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/taxation/vat/vatdeclaration/2" schemaLocation="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/taxation/vat/vatdeclaration/2">
    <ID>123-AAA</ID>
    <Date>2017-04-23</Date>
  <vat:Group>
     <vat:Hdr>
        <vat:ID>833-AAA</vat:ID>
        <vat:DefaultCurrency>GBP</vat:DefaultCurrency>
        <vat:Sender>truth</vat:Sender>
     </vat:Hdr>
  </vat:Group>
</Record>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
    <Data>
<Record xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:vat="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/taxation/vat/vatdeclaration/2" schemaLocation="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/taxation/vat/vatdeclaration/2">
    <ID>123-AAA</ID>
    <Date>2017-04-23</Date>
  <vat:Group>
     <vat:Hdr>
        <vat:ID>833-AAA</vat:ID>
        <vat:DefaultCurrency>GBP</vat:DefaultCurrency>
        <vat:IRmark Type="generic"/>
        <vat:Sender>truth</vat:Sender>
     </vat:Hdr>
  </vat:Group>
</Record>
```

**XSLT Code:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:vat="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/taxation/vat/vatdeclaration/2">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[boolean(normalize-space())]|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="DefaultCurrency">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <vat:IRmark>
            <xsl:attribute name="Type">generic</xsl:attribute>
        </vat:IRmark>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[ancestor-or-self::Group]">
    <xsl:element name="vat:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Record">
    <Record xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:vat="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/taxation/vat/vatdeclaration/2" schemaLocation="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/taxation/vat/vatdeclaration/2">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Record>
</xsl:template>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of template priority. The template that matches `*[ancestor-or-self::Group]` will match also the element `DefaultCurrency`. Because of the condition in the template match, the template has a higher priority (0.5, I think, compared with a priority of 0 for the template matching `DefaultCurrency`) and so this template will be used.

To get around this, assign a manual priority to your template that matches `DefaultCurrency`

```
 <xsl:template match="DefaultCurrency" priority="1">
```

You can read up on conflict resolution for templates at https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict

Comment: http://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/#priority also has a useful table listing the various possibilities.